# display: inline block and vertically centred

Tags: html, css

I have three divs and I want them to display beside each other and centred. It goes image, 1px divider then text. I want them to be vertically centred compared to the ones beside them.

HTML

```
    <div class="sub-logo-wrap">
        <div class="sub-logo"><img src="..." width="auto" height="30px" /></div>            
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="sub-logo-text"><p>text ... can be more than one line ... </p></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.sub-logo-wrap > div { 
  display: inline-block; 
}

.divider { 
  width: 1px;
  height: 20px;
}

.sub-logo-text { 
  width: 150px; 
}
```

the problem is when the text goes to more than one line the centering of the text no longer works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done easily.

```
.sub-logo-wrap > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zgky8dq6/)**</kbd>

Also add this if you need extra accuracy.

```
.sub-logo img {
    display: block;
}
```

Or

```
.sub-logo img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
.sub-logo-wrap > div { 
  display: inline-block; 
  vertical-align: top;
}
.sub-logo-text {
  line-height: 30px; /* Image height */ 
  width: 150px; 
}
```

You can, also, use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```
.sub-logo-wrap {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: center;
 align-content: center;
}
.sub-logo-wrap > div {
 /* No need to add display: inline-block */
}
```

Comment: I apologize, I just finished editing my question (the end wasn't applied) its when the text goes to more than one line that the issue occurs. I am not in full control of that so line height won't work in the way you described